# How can I create a thread that works in the background without blocking the main thread (python), and is using queue causing the main thread to block?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, queue, background-process

I am creating an application using Django, there is a function (webasto_function) that is suppose to do a heavy processing, this same function contains a plotly dash app (app layout and all), so as normal this function should return  a dash component.
In my main code, I call my function (webasto_function) and when the results are ready, I redirect to the HTML page to show the results. As I have said, this function is heavy, so I want to create a thread that handles this function and that runs in the background, while being able to continue using other features of my application meanwhile. And when the (webasto_function) terminates, redirect me to the results page.
To do that, i have created a separate thread (called p) o handle the webasto_function, while using a queue, I have used the queue to store a flag variable that says when the webasto_function terminates. And my main function always checks whether the queue is empty or not, if empty, it waits. Otherwise, if a value is found in the queue (which indicates that the function has already finished), it redirects me to the results HTML page.
The function does what it is expected to do, however, my problem is that when the thread responsible for the implementation of (webasto_function) is processed, it blocks the main thread and I cannot explore other features of the application until the processing is done.

So, in other words, either the thread is not implemented in the background, which blocks the main thread, or the queue is causing the problem, do anyone knows how to handle this.

```
def read_webasto_csv(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        values_from_user = request.POST.getlist('seuil_vit')[0]
    
        q = multiprocessing.Queue()
        p = threading.Thread(target=webasto_function, args=(values_from_user, request, q), daemon=True,name="Thread_webasto")
        p.start()
        print("Process Started Successfully")

        start = time.time()
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)  
            end = time.time()
            print("Time Running Webasto function " , f'time: {end - start:.1f}', end='\r')

                if q.empty():  
                   print("Queue is still empty, just wait.")
                   continue
                else:
                    print("The Background Process has finished and Prepared the results successfully")
                    print("The queue variable value is: ", q.get())
                    return redirect(results_webasto)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you understand that it is impossible to give a proper suggestion without knowing exactly what happens in this ominous `webasto_function`. So I can only give general pointers.

First of all, if you are not already aware of this, you should read up on the [`GIL`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock), which makes Python... let's say *special* with regards to threading. This is something that often trips up people coming from other languages and assuming that threads work as expected in Python. They don't.

Depending on what exactly it is you want to do, you could go (at least) two routes: [Asynchronous](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) code (which Django supports already) or a [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)-based implementation similar to what you already have. Both of these have already been discussed and compared to threading multiple times in great detail on this site and elsewhere, so I won't waste your time here.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. As for the webasto_function, it does not matter what it contains in my question, you can just consider it as a function that runs a loop from 1 to billion, and when it ends it updates a flag and puts it in the queue. My questions here were, am I doing something wrong with declaring the thread so it would not run in the background and it blocks the main thread, is there other ways to make sure to declare a thread that runs in the background? , also, can using a queue be the reason for the problem? so does using a queue normally block other threads?